# How to read a file (containing a mxn matrix) row by row and in each row, element by element?

Tags: file, matrix, fortran

I have a file named "test.dat" that contains a 10x6 matrix as follow:

> test.dat file's contents:

---

> 2 5 9 0 0 0
>   1 3 7 6 0 0
>   0 0 0 0 0 0
>   0 0 0 0 0 0
>   1 0 0 0 0 0
>   0 0 0 0 0 0
>   4 6 0 0 0 0
>   3 0 0 0 0 0
>   2 1 0 0 0 0
>   0 0 0 0 0 0

I want to turn this matrix to a 10x10 matrix which contents are as follow:

> desired test1.dat file's contents:

---

> 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
>   1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
>   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
>   0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

test1.dat is a 10x10 matrix which has rows constructed by this method: for example row 1 of file test1.dat, `0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0`, was actually row 1 of file test.dat, `2 5 9 0 0 0`, with this difference that it's length changed from 6 to 10 and its `i`th element (which was shown in test.dat's first row) was replaced by `1`. i.e. test.dat's first row actually says that this row should expand to 10 element and its 2nd, 5th and 9th element should be replaced by "1" and the rest with zero.
To transform test.dat (matrix A(10x6)) to test1.dat(matrix B(10x10)) I have to first read each row of test.dat element by element and for that for example "j"th row, if its element was equal to for example "z", I write `b(j,z)=1` (B's (j,z) element). So far, I just could try to read "A", element by element as follow:

> ```
>    program test1  
>       Integer (kind=8) :: c  
>       integer (kind = 8) :: g, h  
>       INTEGER, DIMENSION(10,6) :: z  
>       open (unit=20, file="test.dat", access="sequential", form="formatted")  
>       do g=1,6  
>               Read(20,*) z  
>               write (*, *) z  
>       end do  
>    end program test1
> ```

This piece of code will read each line element by element and will write it. Am I right? But I get the following runtime error:

> At line 7 of file test1.f90 (unit = 20, file = 'test.dat')
>   Fortran runtime error: End of file

Now my questions are:

> 1. Is this code written right?
> 2. What is the problem with this code that I get the aforementioned error?
> 3. How can I achieve the rest of the procedure to get "test1.dat file"?

I appreciate it if anyone helps me in here.

> P.S. Machine info:
>   "Linux 3.16.6-200.fc20.x86_64 (fedora 20)"
>   "gcc version 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-7) (GCC)"
>   "using .f90"

Answer (score 1):

No, the code is not correct.  Consider the loop

```
  do g=1,6  
          Read(20,*) z  
          write (*, *) z  
  end do
```

This attempts to read all 60 elements of `z` 6 times.  There aren't enough numbers in the file and the run-time system encounters the end of the file before it finishes - with the result you have observed.

A simple approach to reading the file line-by-line would be to modify the loop like this:

```
  do g=1,10  
          Read(20,*) z(g,:)  
          write (*, *) z(g,:)    
  end do
```

This version reads `z` one line at a time.

Before you ask your next question spend some time researching this sort of straightforward routine.  Here on SO there are several near-duplicate questions from which you could have figured out the problems, and fixed them, yourself.

Comment: So, if I want to read each row, element by element, I should add another loop to your suggested loop as `do h=1,6; write (*, *) z(g,h); end do`. Right? But in the latter case, I do not have the control of the elements. i.e., for example if I would like to reach to a matrix `C(10x6)` with rows as the aforementioned matrix `A(10x6)`'s rows, but in reverse, and in the same order of rows, what should I do? e.g what should I do, if I would like to change the first row of matrix `A`, `2 5 9 0 0 0`, `to , 0 0 0 9 5 2`, and set it as the first row of matrix `C`?

Comment: I know that I can read each row backwards if I change the aforementioned additional loop in the last comment to `h=6,1,-1`, but how can I set them in one row? i.e. with the described procedure, I just get lines reading each row backwards, but I cannot set them in matrix `C`'s rows. In another words, I have not enough control of the elements.

Comment: Don't put new questions in comments.  If you have further questions ask further questions.  But pay attention to my last paragraph above and show, in future questions, some evidence that you have made a serious attempt to solve your own problems.

Comment: It's the same question with an example: "how to have control of elements of an matrix?". But I took your advice and renewed the question in a new question titled "How to put one file's contents in a matrix?".